# Get only users that do not have the id equal to a condition and are admin(SQL)

Tags: mysql, database, t-sql

I have two tables, user:

| id | full_name | is_admin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jane | 0 |
| 2 | Helio | 0 |
| 3 | fran | 0 |
| 4 | mila | 0 |
| 5 | admin | 1 |

approver :

| id | subordinate_id | approver_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |

and I would like to perform a query that brings up the user names that do not have the id in the subordinate_id column of the approvers table.

I tried it this way:

```
SELECT 
    full_name
FROM user AS U 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM approver AS A 
WHERE A.subordinate_id = U.id AND U.is_admin = 0);
```

but in this case the admin user is still coming, and I would like to not bring whoever has the is_admin column of the usuario table = 1. I want to bring only common users and not admin.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT full_name FROM user AS U 
left join approver as A on U.id = a.subordinate_id 
where A.id is null AND U.is_admin = 0
```

Comment: tksss!! this works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `AND U.is_admin = 0` outside `EXISTS`

```
create table `user`(
 id int,
 full_name varchar(20),
 is_admin int
);

create table `approver`(
 id int,
 subordinate_id int,
 approver_id int
);

insert into `user`(id,full_name,is_admin) values
(1,'jane',0),
(2,'Helio',0),
(3,'fran',0),
(4,'mila',0),
(5,'admin',1);

insert into `approver`(id,subordinate_id,approver_id) values
(1,1,2),
(2,3,4);

SELECT 
    full_name
FROM user AS U 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT A.* FROM approver AS A WHERE A.subordinate_id = U.id )
AND U.is_admin = 0
```

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nTxbAca7jdppBfQxqt6dvW/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query. We can select the admin="0" in the first table the can left join on second table. And after that We can do the inverse of inner join to get the results you are expecting.

```
SELECT fullname
FROM
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE is_admin="0") U
LEFT JOIN Approver A
ON U.id=A.subordinate_id
WHERE A.subordinate_id IS NULL;
```